# Update date timetsamp in parent when child is updated spring and mysql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I the following mappings:

MedicalRecord Entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="patient_ref")
    private Patient patient;
```

Prescription Entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="med_rec_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private MedicalRecord medicalRecord;
```

The contoller:

```
@PostMapping("/patients/medical-records/{id}/prescriptions")
    public Prescription addPrescription(@PathVariable int id,
                                        @RequestBody Prescription prescription){

        MedicalRecord medicalRecord = medicalRecordService.getRecord(id); 
        medicalRecord.addPrescription(prescription);

        return prescriptionService.addPrescription(prescription);
    }
```

I have a column in medical record for date in sql with on create and on update timestamp.

I want the date (timestamp) on medical record (parent) to be updated when prescription (child) is updated or inserted with new data.

When I save the prescription I believe it should also save the parent that is the medical record.

However, it does not seem to update the date on the medical record (parent).

Help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: are you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks @PreUpdate, @PostUpdate [Refer this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html)

You can use annotations @LastModifiedDate [Refer this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jpa-auditing-automatically-the-good-stuff)